# Updating Android Application

Tags: android

a while ago I had a developer make an Android application for me. Now, there are some users reporting a bug. I've google'd a little and read something about a keystore. Is it possible for another developer rather than the original one to update this application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Anyone can update this application of yours. The only and the most critical part of this, however, is, as you rightly mention, the keystore. You will need to sign the updated application with the same keystore as the earlier version. Google won't allow you to update the existing app in the Android Market if the keystore is not the same as the one used to sign the existing app.

So bottom line, if you have the original keystore, use it to sign the update regardless of who works on it.

Reference Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html